# p-value (Стьюдента) для оценки статистической значимости коэффициентов регрессии без библиотеки scipy.stats

Tags: python

Как на Python получить p-value (Стьюдента) для оценки статистической значимости коэффициентов регрессии без библиотеки scipy.stats? Не могу сделать код.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, что вы пытались сделать и что именно не получилось

Comment: Смотрите исходники да делаете так же )  https://github.com/scipy/scipy

Comment: не получилось вычленить базовую формулу. то, что я находил, оно все ссылается на таблицы Стьюдента

Answer (score 1):

Ответ наверное дял вас в чем-то неожиданный, но все-таки напишу.

Если очень хочется  получить "оценку статистической значимости коэффициентов регрессии без библиотеки scipy.stats", то надо взять учебник, выписать формулу, по которой эта оценка считается и ее запрограммировать. Все, никаких хитрых хитростей.

Теоретически у вас могут возникнуть при этом два вопроса -

> 1. найти книги с такими формулами
> 2. написать простенькие программы по этим формулам

В каком из этих вопросов у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: Вы правы. Именно так и я пытался поступить - найти формулу в книгах. Перечитал ряд книг и не обнаружил какую-то четкую формулу без таблиц Стьюдента и прочей сложности.

Comment: @Viktor Andriichuk А чудес не бывает. Если в формуле стоит коэффициент, зависящий от выбранного вами  уровня достоверности, то вам надо либо в таблицу лезть (классический, "докомпьютерный" подход), либо аппроксимировать соответствующее распределение (например -  распределение Стьюдента) и потом искать соответствующий квантиль . Этот подход, разумеется вычислительно намного сложнее предыдущего. А что вы предполагали? Что можно обойтись без "сложности", а в учебниках она только что-бы мучить несчастных студентов?

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
from scipy import stats

MSE = (sum((y-y_pred)**2))/(len(X)-len(X[0]))

var_b = MSE*(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X.T,X)).diagonal())

sd_b = np.sqrt(var_b)

ts_b = theta / sd_b

p_values = [2*(1-stats.t.cdf(np.abs(i),(len(X)-1))) for i in ts_b]

sd_b = np.round(sd_b,3)
ts_b = np.round(ts_b,3)
p_values = np.round(p_values,3)
coeff = np.round(theta,4)

myDF3 = pd.DataFrame()
myDF3["Coefficients"],myDF3["Standard Errors"],myDF3["t values"],myDF3["p_values"] = [coeff,sd_b,ts_b,p_values]
print(myDF3)
```

Comment: Извините, но это решением считаться не может. Вопрос вы задали вот так: "p-value (Стьюдента) .... без библиотеки scipy.stats" а в вашей программе явно написано stats.t.cdf.  Вы просто  заменили поиск таблице на обращение к функции, которая считает эти-же значения  внутри себя.